# Are there sub-exponential local complex partition functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, many-body

Consider an arbitrary local, translation-invariant, classical statistical lattice model such as the Ising or Potts model. The partition function $Z$ is a sum over products of local Boltzmann weights, and each summand is positive. Taking the maximal local Boltzmann weight everywhere, we can get an upper bound of $Z$ like
$$ Z < e^{\alpha V},$$
for some $\alpha$, where $V$ is the volume. Similarily, we can get a lower bound by taking the smallest local Boltzmann weight everywhere:
$$ Z > e^{\beta V}\;.$$
In other words, the free energy $F=\ln Z$ extensive,
$$ \beta V < F < \alpha V$$

Now, allow negative or even complex Boltzmann weights, such as we get if we consider the path integral of a quantum model. We still have the same exponential upper bound to $|Z|$. However, the lower bound doesn't work anymore as the different summands can be non-positive and add up destructively (similar to what we observe in the context of the sign problem).

*My question*: For complex Boltzmann weights, it still a lower bound to $|Z|$ exponential in $V$? Is there any proof for this? Or, are there counter examples? That is, are there models for which $Z$ vanishes faster than any exponential, e.g.
$$|Z|<Z_0 e^{-\alpha V^2}\;.$$
Surely, there are models for which $Z$ is exactly $0$ for certain system sizes (e.g., every odd system size), and those system sizes would have to be exempt.

Comment: If your partition vanishes (or grows) faster than any exponential in the volume, then the free energy density would diverge. Of course, you're right to say that if you allow complex coupling constants/magnetic field, then the partition function will vanish at some points. Indeed, the partition function is just a polynomial in the relevant variables (say $e^{\beta J}$ or $e^{\beta h}$ in the Ising model) and is therefore guaranteed to have zeros. This is actually the very basis of the Lee-Yang theory of phase transitions.